# Codeigniter order_by()

Tags: codeigniter, sql-order-by

I am building a blog in Codeigniter to get more familiar with it and to help my PHP and CI skills. on my main page where I am displaying posts I am trying to get the newest post to show first but my below code is not working. any thoughts? I have looked and found some info that I have added to the code but it still is not working. The below does not have any errors when I load the page but it is not ordering them either.

Thanks in advance

```
$data['posts'] = $this->db->order_by('post_id','DECS')->get('posts', $config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

Comment: Thank you for that spelling correction. it didnt fix the issue but it def would have come up sooner or later

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to mixing codes together of MODEL and Controller of MVC framework like CodeIgniter. you should follow MVC pattern. So Try to keep code in controller as

```
$data['posts'] =$this->MODEL_NAME->METHOD_NAME(param1, param2,param2..);
```

Code your entire query in Model method as

```
function METHOD_NAME(param1, param2,param2...){
    $this->db->select('table_name.*')->from('table_name');
    $this->db->where( array('tareget_field'=>param1,'tareget_field'=>param2,'tareget_field2'=>param3));
    // You may use limit to get selected rows
    $this->db->limit(param..);
    $this->db->order_by('post_id','desc'); // **Here is your solution**.
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Hope it will work for you!

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for that. Still getting used to OOP i normally just hard code but I am looking to better my coding practice